# How do I overlay different kinds of graph in Seaborn?

Tags: python, plot, graph, overlay, seaborn

I'm trying to get two graphs into the same fig, using different y-axes, and it works fine when I use the same kind of plot (two barplots or two lineplots, for example). Using this code

```
fig, graph = plt.subplots(figsize=(75,3))
sns.lineplot(x='YearBuilt',y='SalePrice',ax=graph,data=processed_data,color='red')
graph2 = graph.twinx()
sns.lineplot(x='YearBuilt', y='AvgOverallQual',ax=graph2,data=processed_data,color='teal')
```

I obtain this

[image]

But when I try to use different kinds, like this:

```
fig, graph = plt.subplots(figsize=(75,3))
sns.barplot(x='YearBuilt',y='SalePrice',ax=graph,data=processed_data,color='red')
graph2 = graph.twinx()
sns.lineplot(x='YearBuilt', y='AvgOverallQual',ax=graph2,data=processed_data,color='teal')
```

my graph looks like:

[image]

How do I overlay different kinds of graph in Seaborn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A seaborn `barplot` is a categorical plot. The first bar will be at position 0, the second at position 1 etc. A `lineplot` is a numeric plot; it will put all points at a position given by the numeric coordinates.

Here, it seems there is no need to use seaborn at all. Since matplotlib `bar` plots are numerical as well, doing this in matplotlib alone will give you the desired overlay

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(75,3))
ax.bar('YearBuilt','SalePrice', data=processed_data, color='red')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot('YearBuilt', 'AvgOverallQual', data=processed_data, color='teal')
```

Comment: Yeah, I already did it in matplotlib and I guess it works fine to this purpose. But I was struggling to understand why it wasn't working in seaborn and it makes much more sense now. Your answer was very helpful, thanks!